# SVG and rectangle line thickness in Safari?

Tags: svg, safari

I am experiencing an issue with Safari 9.0.2 on MacOS X 10.11, where it seems to draw the lines in SVG thicker than in other browsers on the same computer. I can't tell whether this is something I need to tweak in my SVG settings or whether this is an issue with Safari. Note this does not seem to impact regular lines.

A screen capture of what I am seeing:

[image]

and the code I use to generate it:

https://jsfiddle.net/ajmas/jh3144b3/

or just the essential code (using Snap SVG):

```
centerX = snap.node.clientWidth / 2;
centerY = snap.node.clientHeight / 2;

for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
  width = 20 + (i*20);
  height = width;
  snap.rect(centerX - width/2, centerY - height/2, width, height).attr({
     'stroke': 'black',
     'stroke-width': i + 'px',
     'fill': 'none'
  });
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I am going to put this down to an SVG rendering 'bug' in WebKit, and have opened up a bug report. There is also an issue in Firefox on the Mac where vertical lines aren't the same thickness as the horizontal lines, in a rectangle.